# Switching between two separate accounts to play Pokemon Go on one device

Tags: pokemon-go

I wondered if it is possible to switch between two accounts so one can be used by myself as the main account while the other can be used by my child.
So can I use that as a potential way to have 2 save files?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can simply switch between 2 accounts. The save data will be the one belonging to the account you currently are logged in with.

The only way this could backfire at you is if you'd abuse with either of those, but that always backfires.

It doesn't need to be a Google and a Trainer account though, it can simply be 2 Google accounts if you'd want to.

Comment: Ok thanks, its just quicker to set up Poke trainer club account than a new Google one.

Comment: In their other game, Ingress, using two accounts, one for each faction, from one player or device, is seen as very bad behavior, but in PoGo the teams don't really have a very strong part in the game *yet*. I'd say best to have both accounts be on the same team, to run the least risk of future upset.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  but you would need two separate accounts for that. Such as two different google accounts or one google account and one pokemon trainer account, or two different pokemon trainer accounts.

To access the other account, just sign out of your account and sign into the other one

Comment: That's ok, ive got my main on google and have just signed up to Pokémon trainer club I didn't want to lose my main account if I switched it up. Many thanks

Comment: @Callum your welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can just sign out and sign in to your other account, but beware it is against the Pokemon Go Trainer guidelines posted by Niantic to have multiple accounts, since you will be playing on the same device there is a good chance that they may think you are going against this rule and playing on two accounts.

> **No Cheating.**
>
> Don’t do it. Play fair. Pokémon GO is meant to be played on a mobile device and get you outside to explore your world! Methods of cheating, unfortunately, are limited only by cheaters’ imaginations, but include at a minimum the following: using modified or unofficial software; playing with multiple accounts (one account per player, please); sharing accounts; using tools or techniques to alter or falsify your location; or selling/trading accounts.

https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221993967-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO-Trainer-guidelines

Comment: Niantic does a pretty good job of ensuring that players are not using multiple accounts. They don't wave that ban-hammer too loosely or without reason. So long as they are legitimately using it as two separate people (and not just to increase storage, to swap gyms, or other related tactics like in Ingress) they should be fine. Having a second account for your child is, after all, still one account per player.

Answer (score 0):

Even we can run **Pokemon Go Multiple accounts** simultaneously on any android device but we **shouldn't** do this to run two accounts at the same time as it could result a ban. However this could help us to switch b/w multiple accounts quickly without logging in or out. So you can easily manage two Pokemon Go accounts for you and your child or any other family member. You just need only first time Pokemon Go login and then no need to login and logout again and again.
Here is the method described with Pros&Cons to [run and switch b/w Pokemon Go multiple accounts simultaneously without losing game data](http://tabaxis.com/run-pokemon-go-multiple-accounts-simultaneously/).

Comment: Are you sure that using this tool is a good idea? This seems like it would be against Niantic's TOS...

Comment: It shouldn't be against TOS if you don't open multiple accounts at the same time. This method is good to switch b/w multiple accounts easily.

Comment: That's not true. Niantic has a strict ["one account = one human" policy](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221993967-Pokémon-GO-Trainer-guidelines)

Comment: But accounts shouldn't be banned when two human of one family want to play Pokemon Go. There is option to signin and signout which is more beneficial to multiple accounts, no one required to signout from ac when he/she have personal handset. OR parents should buy a separate phone for the kids who want to just play Pokemon Go? It's pretty annoying and not a good policy. Separately, Yeah it would be difficult for Niantic to differentiate b/w real users and spammers.

Comment: "Separately, Yeah it would be difficult for Niantic to differentiate b/w real users and spammers." <- this is why it's not recommended that you use two accounts on one device. You run the risk of being banned, even if you aren't cheating.